# How to access images in the local storage?

Tags: laravel, qr-code, laravel-9, google-2fa

I'm working on a project which has to retrieve some data from the local storage. I'm saving a personal image to the locale storage, but when I'm trying to retrieve the image I'm getting 404 ERROR.

Error: http://localhost:8000/storage/app/img.png

This is the way I'm trying to get the image:

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/img.png') }}" />`

I red the Laravel documentation, but I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Did you check asset path?

Comment: Laravel docs: You may use the url method to get the URL for a given file. If you are using the local driver, this will typically just prepend /storage to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. But I tried that also, and it didnt work.

Comment: You may use the storage helper as well.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is that mean exactly?

Comment: Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-local-driver

Comment: You could use: `Storage::disk('local')->get'img.png');`

Comment: I'm gonna try that later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are set the symlink with: `php artisan storage:link`.

Afterwards you can check:
`<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/img.png') }}" />` or:
`<img src="{{ asset('storage/img.png') }}" />`

Comment: Symlink to storage is only needed if we're dealing with public folder inside storage.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Thanks for comment. But if you use the asset helper function you expect to have access to the public folder or not?

Comment: Depends on the use case.

Comment: That's my problem. I don't want to add it to the public folder.

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/img.png') }}" />` Opening an image via a browser is very clearly  `public` for me.

Comment: The laravel docs said that if you save something into the LOCAL storage you have to use /storage so something like this I think: localhost:8000/storage/x.png. But this also not works for me.

Comment: @daniel19 ok. My mistake. Then I'm afraid I don't know either. Because in such a case I would work with an auth.

Comment: Is there anyway to create a symbolic link for local storage?

Comment: @daniel19 Create a `private/images` folder in your storage/app/ folder. Create A route (`images/private/{image}`) and a new Controller. Maybe named: ImageHandlerController. Inside you will have a public method where you fetch the request and pass the requested image as parameter.  Then you can build the path `private/images/' . $image`. To make it private you have to implement auth. That would be the eaysiest way.

Comment: @daniel19 You need a condition to distinguish who can see the picture and who cannot. And Auth would be the simplest way to do that. If you are only allowed to see the picture, then you can query in your method. auth()->user->email === "daniel.xy@email.com" . You could probably also work with tokens but that would only make it more complex.

Comment: @daniel19 Cool! And thank you for feedback. how did you do it?